# What is the difference between thinkpad-isa-0000 and coretemp-isa-0000 temperatures?

Tags: 20.04, temperature, lm-sensors

After installing `lm-sensors`, I can run `sensors` and the output is

```
ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +20.00 V)
curr1:         3.00 A  (max =  +3.25 A)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.0°C  

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +56.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          17.29 V  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +37.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        2489 RPM
fan2:        2174 RPM
CPU:          +37.0°C  
GPU:              N/A  
temp3:         +0.0°C  
temp4:         +0.0°C  
temp5:         +0.0°C  
temp6:         +0.0°C  
temp7:         +0.0°C  
temp8:            N/A  

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +45.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +77.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +45.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +37.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
```

I am curious to know what is the difference between the `coretemp-isa-0000` temperatures from the cores and the `thinkpad-isa-0000/CPU`. Is the CPU temperature an average from all the cores?